# chrome button not click (element not visible) using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

im trying to click this specific button but it seems its not working can someone help me?

heres what i wrote

```
obj.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class='btn btn-warning waves-effect m-1' and @id='btn-create-beneficiary' and text()=' Create Beneficiary']").Click



<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="benef_tab">
                                        <div class="d-flex m-b-15" style="justify-content: flex-end;">
                                            <button class="btn btn-warning waves-effect m-1" id="btn-create-beneficiary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createModal" style=""> Create Beneficiary</button>
                                                                                        <button class="btn btn-success waves-effect m-1" data-action="encoding-complete" style="display: none;"><i class="material-icons">done_all</i> Mark as Completed</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-warning waves-effect m-1" data-action="return-beneficiaries" data-id="15945" style="display: none;"><i class="material-icons">assignment_return</i> Return For Re-check</button>
                                            <button class="btn bg-teal waves-effect m-1" data-action="undo-completeness" style="display: none;"><i class="material-icons">replay</i> Undo</button>
                                                                                    </div>                                            
                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <div id="benefTable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap no-footer"><div class="dt-buttons"><a class="dt-button buttons-excel buttons-html5 btn bg-pink waves-effect" tabindex="0" aria-controls="benefTable" href="#"><span>Excel Download</span></a></div><div id="benefTable_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>Filter Result <small class="text-muted">(ID,NAME)</small>:<input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="benefTable"></label></div><div id="benefTable_processing" class="dataTables_processing" style="display: none;"><div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
                    <div class="preloader pl-size-xs">
                        <div class="spinner-layer pl-red-grey">
                            <div class="circle-clipper left">
                                <div class="circle"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-clipper right">
                                <div class="circle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA
First, set your reference to the Selenium WebDrive in the References tool...
Then the following code:

''*************************************************

Dim MyButton as Selenium.WebElement

Set MyButton = Obj.FindElementByCSS("#btn-create-beneficiary")

MyButton.Click